# Server disconnected (code: 1006) openstack

Tags: console, vnc, openstack

Trying to connect to my VM instance when all of a sudden I get this error from the console:

```
Server disconnected (code: 1006)
```

All I did was move from one room to another (changing Ethernet cables). Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this at your house or at work?  Your question is vague and I'm wondering if your server now has a new IP and you might need to disassociate the current floating IP and re-associate it with a new floating IP.  You can do that from the instance page using the dropdown for the specific instance.

Also try soft/hard rebooting the VM instance after doing the previous step and see if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "novncproxy_host" option under nova.conf ( vi /etc/nova/nova.conf) file 
if the novncproxy_host IP is set as 0.0.0.0 change it with your Controller IP where the Nova Proxy service is running.

novncproxy_host=172.25.20.10